# Switch stylesheets and remember it using jquery.cookie.js

Tags: jquery, css, html, cookies, local-storage

Probably has been already asked before but I still haven't found any useful or complete answer yet.How can we switch stylesheets and save the one that has been selected in jQuery cookie or local storage?

So I'm having like 5 stylesheets located in the same folder. So I don't think I must type them all in my html file, am I? Thank you.

```
<link href="styles/black.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="black">
<link href="styles/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="blue">
<link href="styles/green.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="green">
<link href="styles/red.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="red">
<link href="styles/yellow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="yellow">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create the `<link>` element using jQuery, reading the color from `localStorage`, and append it to the `<head>`:

```
var styleColor = localStorage.styleColor || "black"; // Using "black" as default
$("<link>", {
    rel: "stylesheet",
    href: "styles/" + styleColor + ".css"
}).appendTo("head");
```

This gets tricky if you want to hot swap the stylesheet.  You then need to find the `<link>` element and remove it, then replace it with the one you want.  I'm not even sure if that would work.

But, may I suggest an alternative?  It might be better to have one stylesheet, and then use classes to select the theme.  Set the theme class on the `<html>` element, and define your styles based on theme.

For example, suppose your body background color changes per theme.  You could then define your styles like this:

```
.red body { background-color: red; }
.blue body { background-color: blue; }
```

Then changing themes would be as simple as calling this function, passing in the theme name:

```
function loadTheme(theme) {
    $("html").removeClass("red blue").addClass(theme);
}
```

Then, to use `localStorage` a couple more utility functions:

```
function saveTheme(theme) {
    localStorage.theme = theme;
}
function getTheme() {
    return localStorage.theme || "black";
}
```

Don't even use `document.ready` to load the theme.  You want your stylesheet to load before your content.  Call this from a script element in the `<head>`:

```
loadTheme(getTheme());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Your alternative is not bad but it will be an exhausting work for those who need to rebuild their existing stylesheets including me.I have many elements so typing for each one of them the class in front of it it will take a lot of time. So i'm more interested in switching stylesheets.Can you provide an example please for your first suggestion or for using jcookie? Thank you.

Comment: @Eddi - I'm not sure what you are asking...  How to use jcookie instead of `localStorage`?

Comment: Well,from what i know you can save the statement/class either in local storage ( directly inside the browser, no jquery plugin need ) or by including a plugin like this one github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.As i said i apologize if i am wrong.